# Successive localizations of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, localization

I am trying to prove the following:

> Suppose that $p\subseteq q$ are prime ideals in $R$ and $M$ is an $R$-module. Then the the localization of the $R$-module $M_{q}$ at $p$ is $M_{p}$, i.e., $(M_{q})_{p}=M_{p}$.

I have tried to use the fact that $M_{p}\simeq R_{p} \otimes M$  as R-modules but I couldn't get the statement. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hint: write out everything in fractals and try to see it explicitly.

Comment: First try to show $(R_{q})_{p} = R_{p} \otimes R_{q} = R_{p}$. Once this is done then $M_{p} = R_{p} \otimes M = R_{p} \otimes (R_{q} \otimes M) $. Obviously as the above comment suggests: it is easier to try writing things out in fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $A\to B$ a (commutative) $A$-algebra, $B\to C$ a $B$-algebra, $M$ an $A$-module. There is a canonical isomorphism:
$$(N\otimes_A B)\otimes_B C\simeq M\otimes_A C.$$